# remember me feature for login page

Tags: php

i need remember me feature in my code. i'm set session but i don't know idea about set cookie for remember me. please set remember me code in below my login page. i'm tried many sites but i'm not get exact output.

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("pratice") or die (mysql_error());
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$remember=$_POST['remember'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql="select id, username FROM `action2` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num>0)
{
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $username=$row['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    header("location:userpage.php");
}
else 
{
echo"<p><center><b><font color='red'>Incorrect Username or Password!</font></b></center></p>";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">LOGIN</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><input name="remember" type="checkbox" value=""/></td>
    <td>Remember me</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="LogIn" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php -> Five seconds on Google.

Comment: Refer this [link](http://evolt.org/node/60265/)

Comment: What you had tried? this code shows that you didn't tried anything.At least make an effort to search on google.

Comment: @Vinay that's a dangerously dated (2004) script

Comment: @Dagon Ya, but i just gave him reference, so that he can pull something out of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your current file,check whether the `$_SESSION['id']` and `$_SESSION['username']` are set or not. I yes, you can directly redirect the user to `userpage.php`.

```
if($_SESSION['id'] != "" && $_SESSION['username'] != "")
{
    header("location:userpage.php");
}
```

If you want to do this on checking "remember me",you can use javascript or jquery.